Rolling window selection with groupby in pandas
I have the following pandas dataframe:
# Create the DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
    'date': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12],
    'value': [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28]
})
df

id  date    value
0   1   1   11
1   1   2   12
2   1   3   13
3   1   4   14
4   1   5   15
5   1   6   16
6   1   7   17
7   1   8   18
8   2   5   21
9   2   6   22
10  2   7   23
11  2   8   24
12  2   9   25
13  2   10  26
14  2   11  27
15  2   12  28

I want to query the above dataframe, in a rolling window manner, for both ids. The rolling window should be of size n.
So, if n==2, in the 1st iteration I would like to query this:
df.query('(id==1 and (date==1 or date==2)) or (id==2 and (date==5 or date==6))')
id  date    value
0   1   1   11
1   1   2   12
8   2   5   21
9   2   6   22

in the 2nd iteration I would like to query this:
df.query('(id==1 and (date==2 or date==3)) or (id==2 and (date==6 or date==7))')
id  date    value
1   1   2   12
2   1   3   13
9   2   6   22
10  2   7   23

in the 3rd iteration I would like to query this:
df.query('(id==1 and (date==3 or date==4)) or (id==2 and (date==7 or date==8))')
id  date    value
2   1   3   13
3   1   4   14
10  2   7   23
11  2   8   24

etc. How could I do that in pandas ? My data has around 500 ids

What do you mean by "iteration"? Are you going to loop over these? Which operation will you perform? Do the groups have the same size?

By iteration I mean the "window" iteration. In the first "window loop" sort to say.
The operation that I want to perform is to simply put the queried dataframe and print it.
Yes, each id does has the same size

If you want to print, then looping is an appropriate approach (printing is more expensive than looping)

The exact expected logic is not fully clear, but assuming you want to loop over the groups/rolls, you could combine groupby.nth with sliding_window_view. By reusing the DataFrameGroupBy object, will only need to compute the groups once:
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view as swv

n = 2

max_size = df['id'].value_counts(sort=False).max()
g = df.sort_values(by=['id', 'date']).groupby('id', sort=False)

for idx in swv(np.arange(max_size), n):
    print(f'rows {idx}')
    print(g.nth(idx))

Output:
rows [0 1]
   id  date  value
0   1     1     11
1   1     2     12
8   2     5     21
9   2     6     22
rows [1 2]
    id  date  value
1    1     2     12
2    1     3     13
9    2     6     22
10   2     7     23
rows [2 3]
    id  date  value
2    1     3     13
3    1     4     14
10   2     7     23
11   2     8     24
rows [3 4]
    id  date  value
3    1     4     14
4    1     5     15
11   2     8     24
12   2     9     25
rows [4 5]
    id  date  value
4    1     5     15
5    1     6     16
12   2     9     25
13   2    10     26
rows [5 6]
    id  date  value
5    1     6     16
6    1     7     17
13   2    10     26
14   2    11     27
rows [6 7]
    id  date  value
6    1     7     17
7    1     8     18
14   2    11     27
15   2    12     28

Alternatively, and assuming groups with an identical size and sorted by id/date, using shifted indexing:
n = 2
ngroups = df['id'].nunique()
for idx in swv(np.arange(len(df)).reshape(-1, ngroups, order='F'), n, axis=0):
    print(f'indices: {idx.ravel()}')
    print(df.iloc[idx.flat])

Output:
indices: [0 1 8 9]
   id  date  value
0   1     1     11
1   1     2     12
8   2     5     21
9   2     6     22
indices: [ 1  2  9 10]
    id  date  value
1    1     2     12
2    1     3     13
9    2     6     22
10   2     7     23
indices: [ 2  3 10 11]
    id  date  value
2    1     3     13
3    1     4     14
10   2     7     23
11   2     8     24
indices: [ 3  4 11 12]
    id  date  value
3    1     4     14
4    1     5     15
11   2     8     24
12   2     9     25
indices: [ 4  5 12 13]
    id  date  value
4    1     5     15
5    1     6     16
12   2     9     25
13   2    10     26
indices: [ 5  6 13 14]
    id  date  value
5    1     6     16
6    1     7     17
13   2    10     26
14   2    11     27
indices: [ 6  7 14 15]
    id  date  value
6    1     7     17
7    1     8     18
14   2    11     27
15   2    12     28


I attempted it by looping through each window and setting the start date for each unique id and create the query conditions for each ID dynamically.
n = 2
unique_ids = df['id'].unique()

start_dates = {uid: df[df['id'] == uid]['date'].min() for uid in unique_ids}

for iteration in range(len(df['date'].unique()) - n + 1):
    query_conditions = []
    for uid in unique_ids:
        start_date = start_dates[uid] + iteration
        end_date = start_date + n - 1
        query_conditions.append(f"(id == {uid} and date >= {start_date} and date <= {end_date})")
    
    query_string = " or ".join(query_conditions)
    result = df.query(query_string)
    
    print(f"Iteration {iteration + 1} Query:")
    print(query_string)
    print(result)
    print("\n")

Output
Iteration 1 Query:
(id == 1 and date >= 1 and date <= 2) or (id == 2 and date >= 5 and date <= 6)
   id  date  value
0   1     1     11
1   1     2     12
8   2     5     21
9   2     6     22


Iteration 2 Query:
(id == 1 and date >= 2 and date <= 3) or (id == 2 and date >= 6 and date <= 7)
    id  date  value
1    1     2     12
2    1     3     13
9    2     6     22
10   2     7     23


Iteration 3 Query:
(id == 1 and date >= 3 and date <= 4) or (id == 2 and date >= 7 and date <= 8)
    id  date  value
2    1     3     13
3    1     4     14
10   2     7     23
11   2     8     24


Iteration 4 Query:
(id == 1 and date >= 4 and date <= 5) or (id == 2 and date >= 8 and date <= 9)
    id  date  value
3    1     4     14
4    1     5     15
11   2     8     24
12   2     9     25


If I understand well what you expect, you can use a simple loop:
L = int(df.shape[0] / len(df["id"].unique()))  # length for each id (here 16/2 = 8)
for i in range(L-1):
    print(f"Iteration {i+1}:")
    print(df.loc[[i, i+1, i+L, i+L+1]])

Iteration 1:
   id  date  value
0   1     1     11
1   1     2     12
8   2     5     21
9   2     6     22
Iteration 2:
    id  date  value
1    1     2     12
2    1     3     13
9    2     6     22
10   2     7     23
Iteration 3:
    id  date  value
2    1     3     13
3    1     4     14
10   2     7     23
11   2     8     24
Iteration 4:
    id  date  value
3    1     4     14
4    1     5     15
11   2     8     24
12   2     9     25
Iteration 5:
    id  date  value
4    1     5     15
5    1     6     16
12   2     9     25
13   2    10     26
Iteration 6:
    id  date  value
5    1     6     16
6    1     7     17
13   2    10     26
14   2    11     27
Iteration 7:
    id  date  value
6    1     7     17
7    1     8     18
14   2    11     27
15   2    12     28


This is not easily generalized to many groups and n much greater than 2.

@mozway, I agree. It would need another loop so less elegant. Your solution is better :-)
